# Find: $\lim_{n\to\infty} r^n$, for $r>1$ and $r<1$

Tags: limits, proof-writing, infinity

Prove: 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}r^n = +\infty\,, r > 1;$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}r^n = 0\,, 0 \le r < 1.$$

I am not quite sure how to prove this, but once someone proves it I will make sure to ask questions if I'm in doubt. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Proofs of the second fact are on [this ProofWiki page](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Power_of_a_Number_Less_Than_One). Proofs that the first follows from the second are on [this page](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Reciprocal_of_Null_Sequence).

Comment: You assume $r>0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps one can add something to the answer by lhf for the case $0\lt r\lt 1$.

For such an $r$, let $r=\dfrac{1}{1+x}$.  Then $x \gt 0$. Now go to the answer by lhf.

Comment: What does the "lhf" stands for?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Use [Bernoulli's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality):
$$
(1+x)^n \ge 1 + nx \quad \mbox{for $x\ge 0$}
$$
This can be proven by induction.

Comment: And of course this would work for both of them :)

Answer (score 0):

I first saw the proof that $r^n \to 0$ if $0 \le r < 1$ 
and $r^n \to \infty$ if $r > 1$
in Courant and Robbin's "What is Mathematics?"
many years ago.
As stated by others, the proof uses
Bernoulli's inequality and,
implicitly, Archimede's axiom
about the real numbers.

They also have a simple proof
that $n^{1/n} \to 1$ as integer $n \to \infty$.

One nice thing about these proofs
is that all the bounds are explicit
and easily computable.