# Convergence of sum of Infinite terms of Geometric Series for x<1

Tags: sequences-and-series

could you please say why the geometric series converges at x<1.When I looked through  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression it says that the series converges at r<1.

where $\sum_n^\infty(a^n)$=$\left(\frac a{1-r}\right)$

I couldn't get the proof of sum of infinite terms of GP where it says:

$S_n$=$a(\frac{1-r^n} {1-r})$ as $n\to\infty$ it becomes $\left(\frac a{1-r}\right)$

Comment: It should be $|r|<1$. The idea is that as $n \to \infty$ with this condition, the term $r^n$ approaches zero.

Comment: could you say why $r^n$ approaches zero.

Comment: @justin: take a pocket calculator and multiply 0.9 by itself repeatedly.

Comment: that's very right.

Comment: @justin [Refer This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211843/find-lim-n-to-infty-rn-for-r1-and-r1)

Answer (score 0):

$$s_n=\sum_{i=0}^n ar^i$$
$$s_n=a+ar+ar^2+\cdots+ar^{n-1}+ar^n$$

$$r\cdot s_n=\ \ ar+ar^2+\cdots+ar^n+ar^{n+1}$$

$$s_n(r-1)=ar^{n+1}-a\Rightarrow s_n=\frac{ar^{n+1}-a}{r-1}=a\left(\frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1}\right)$$

$$\begin{align}s&=a+ar+ar^2+\cdots+0\\
sr&=\ \ \ \ \ \ \ ar+ar^2+\cdots+0\\
s(1-r)&=a
\end{align}$$
$$\Rightarrow s=\frac{a}{1-r}$$

**Note:**

for $|r| \lt 1$  $$\lim_{n \to \infty} r^n=0$$

Comment: It appears the statement in the note, taken for granted, is actually the result the OP is asking about.