# Single Variable Calculus question: Why are these expressions equivalent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Can someone show me how we can prove that the following expression:

$$y = \frac{x}{16\ }\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}^3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}^5}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}^7}+\frac{1}{16}\right... )$$

is equivalent to:

$$y=\frac{x}{16\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}$$

Comment: Are you asking why $$1 + r + r^2 +r^3+ \cdots = \dfrac{1}{1-r}$$ ?

Comment: @rsadhvika Yes!

Comment: good just making sure.. :)

Comment: have you done problems on geometric series before?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/994853/convergence-of-sum-of-infinite-terms-of-geometric-series-for-x1 have a look at this thread.

Comment: @rsadhvika Thank you very much!

Comment: @Rick Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It is $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}q^i=\frac{q}{1-q}$$

Comment: shouldn' t we have some condition on $q$ for the formula to hold?

Comment: Yes we should, $|q|<1$, in the Problem above it is used already.

Answer (score 0):

**Definition.**  A sequence $(a_k)$ is said to be *geometric* if it has a common ratio $r \neq 0$, meaning that 
$$\frac{a_{k + 1}}{a_k} = r$$
for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

The first few terms of a geometric sequence with initial term with initial term $a_1$ are 
\begin{align*}
a_1 &\\
a_2 & = a_1r\\ 
a_3 & = a_2r\\
    & = (a_1r)r\\
    & = a_1r^2\\ 
a_4 & = a_3r\\
    & = (a_1r^2)r\\
    & = a_1r^3
\end{align*}
An explicit formula for the $k$th term of a geometric sequence with initial term $a_1$ is $a_k = a_1r^{k - 1}$.

**Definition.**  A series is said to be *geometric* if it is the sum of the terms of a geometric sequence.
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} a_1r^{k - 1} = a_1 + a_1r + a_1r^2 + a_1r^3 + \cdots$$
where $a \neq 0$ is a constant and $r$ is the *common ratio*.

**Definition.**  The $n$th partial sum of a geometric series is
$$s_n = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} a_1r^{k - 1} = a_1 + a_1r + a_1r^2 + a_1r^2 + \cdots + a_1r^{n - 1} = a_1(1 + r + r^2 + \cdots +r^{n - 1})$$

If $r = 1$, then 
$$s_n = a_1(\underbrace{1 + 1 + 1 + \cdots + 1}_{n~\text{terms}}) = na_1$$
Otherwise, we can multiply $s_n$ by $1 - r$ to obtain
\begin{align*}
(1 - r)s_n & = (1 - r)a_1(1 + r + r^2 + \cdots + r^{n - 1})\\
           & = a_1(1 + r + r^2 + \cdots + r^{n - 1}) - a_1(r + r^2 + \cdots + r^{n - 1} + r^n)\\
           & = a_1(1 - r^n)
\end{align*}
Since $r \neq 1$, $1 - r \neq 0$.  Therefore,
$$s_n = a_1 \frac{1 - r^n}{1 - r}$$
If $|r| < 1$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} r^n = 0$, so 
$$S = \lim_{n \to \infty} s_n = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} a_1r^{k - 1} = a_1\frac{1}{1 - r}$$
In your example, $a_1 = \dfrac{x}{16}$ and $r = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} < 1$, so the series converges to
$$S = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{x}{16}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{k - 1} = \frac{x}{16}\left(\frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\right)$$