# Finding $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {3^{n+1}+3} {3^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

**Lemma 1**: For the sequence $a_n$ defined by $a_n=(\frac 1 {x^n})_{n=1}^\infty$ we have that $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=0$. Where $x\in R$ and $x\ne 0$. *This is the limit of a sequence.

**Proof**: Let $\varepsilon>0$ be a real number. We have to find an $N\ge 1$ such that for al $n> N$ we have that $|\frac {1} {x^n}-0|=|\frac 1 {x^n}|<\varepsilon$. Because $\frac 1 {x^n}$ is positive for all $n\in R$, we can remove the absolute value and take $log_x$ on both sides. $$\frac 1 {x^n} <\varepsilon$$ $$\implies \frac 1 \varepsilon<x^n$$ $$\implies log_x(\frac 1 \varepsilon)<log_x(x^n)$$ $$\implies -log_x(\varepsilon)<n$$

Thus, if we let $N>-log_x(\varepsilon)$, then for all $n> N$ we have that $|\frac 1 {x^n}|<\varepsilon$. This proves that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac 1 {x^n} = 0$.

---

**Problem**: Find $\lim_{n\to \infty} (\frac {3^{n+1}+3} {3^n})$ and prove the result. *This is the limit of a sequence

**Proof**: Note that $$\frac {3^{n+1}+3} {3^n}= \frac {3^{n+1}} {3^n} +\frac {3} {3^n}$$ $$=3+\frac 1 {3^{n-1}}$$

Thus, $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {3^{n+1}+3} {3^n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}3+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1 {3^{n-1}}$$ Using lemma $1$ we conclude that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}3+\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac 1 {3^{n-1}}=3$$

Hence, $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {3^{n+1}+3} {3^n}=3$$

---

**Is this whole thing correct**?

**Edit**: Fixed my algebra mistake. Thanks to everyone in the comments for their help!. I will fix lemma $1$, although it is night here so I will fix it tomorrow.

Comment: Note that $\frac{3}{3^n} = 3^{1 - n} = \frac{1}{3^{n - 1}}$, not $\frac{1}{3^{1 - n}}$.

Comment: Lemma 1 only holds for $\lvert x \rvert > 1$. Also if you're assuming $x$ is positive you should make that clear. Besides that the proof works. You may consider proving the claim by writing $x=1+y$ where $y>0$ and using an inequality such as Bernoulli's Inequality to avoid using $\log$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yeah, I don't know what was I thinking. This proof requires modifications.

Comment: @jcneek Yeah I just realized that, I will tryi to improve and modify the proof.

Comment: Check that you're allowed to use $\log$ in your proof to Lemma $1.$  The $\log$ function is usually defined as a limit, so I'm not sure you can use it in your proof of Lemma $1,$ as then you would be assuming the result and using it in the proof, which is not allowed. Also, I doubt you need to use $\log$ for Lemma $1$; there are probably simpler methods.

Comment: @jcneek Come to think about it, I could use lemma $1$ as $\frac 3 {3^n}=\frac 1 {3^{n-1}}$ and thus lemma $1$ holds as long as $n-1\ge 1$. I will need to modify this for when $n-1<1$.

Comment: @AdamRubinson I am not sure if I am allowed to use the log function.  But I will try to prove it as joneek suggested I prove it using Bernoulli's inequality.

Comment: @Newuser Yea definitely. No need to modify the argument though. $n$ need not necessarily start from $1$,  as long as it tends to infinity through the naturals.

Comment: @jcneek Oh yeah, hadn't though about that. I guess apart from using the log function, my algebra mistake and not stating that $|x|>1$, everything else seems to hold!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit long so I posted it on the answer section. There is a straightforward  proof of your lemma, avoiding more complicated functions.

When $0\lt a\lt 1$ the sequence $a^n$ is decreasing, since  $\frac{a^{n+1}}{a^n}=a\lt 1$ which is the same as $a^{n+1}\lt a^n$. As the sequence is bounded below, it has a limit, say $l$. Hence, $\lim a^{n+1}= a\lim a^n$, or $l=al$, or $(1-a)l=0$. As $a$ is not equal to $1$, we conclude that $l=0$. From this it also follows that the lemma holds for $-1\lt a \le 0$ as well (check this).

Edit: for your specific example, note that $n\lt 3^n$ so that $0\lt \frac{1}{3^n}\lt \frac{1}{n}$. By the squeeze lemma, $\lim \frac{1}{3^n}=0$.

Comment: I like your proof. Where is the "standard form" you refer to in your comment to my question?

Comment: @AdamRubinson Thanks. Actually in almost all elementary analysis books, the lemma proved in my answer is a standard result, for example before analyzing the convergence of the geometric series. This is the “standard formulation” of the lemma that you proved in your answer

Comment: Sorry I don’t get what you mean. We proved the same lemma in different ways. That’s all, no?

Comment: As I said, it’s a matter of pedagogy. You wouldn’t see your formulation of the lemma in any elementary analysis book

Comment: Fair enough....

Answer (score 0):

The proof to the problem is fine, albeit unnecessarily long. Just write:

**Problem**: Find $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac {3^{n+1}+3} {3^n}\right).$

**Answer**: $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {3^{n+1}+3} {3^n}= \lim_{n\to\infty} (3) + \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {3} {3^n}$$

$$=3 + \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac 1 {3^{n-1}}$$

$$ = 3 + 0 = 3. $$

For the proof of the Lemma you *can* use Bernoulli's inequality, but you don't need to. I will re-state [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4225145/29156) presently.

**Lemma 1**: Let $\vert x\vert> 1.$ For the sequence $a_n$ defined by $a_n=\left(\frac 1 {x^n}\right)_{n=1}^\infty$ we have: $\ \displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=0$.

**Proof**: Since $0<\alpha<1$, the sequence $\alpha^n$ is strictly decreasing. Moreover, it is bounded below as $\alpha^n$ is positive for all $n\in\Bbb{N}$. Let $S=\{\alpha^n:n\in\Bbb{N}\}$. By the monotone convergence theorem,
$$
\lim_{n \to\infty}\alpha^n=\inf S \, .
$$
All that is left to show is that $0=\inf S\ $. Let $\ (a_n) = \alpha^n.\ $ Then, $\ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \alpha\ \implies\ a_{n+1} = \alpha\ a_n.\ $ Now suppose $\ \inf\{S\}=x>0.\ $ Then by definition of convergence towards $\ x,\ \exists i\in\mathbb{N}\ $ such that $\ x\leq a_i< \alpha x,\ $ which implies that $\ a_{i+1}=\alpha\ a_i<x,\ $ contradicting $\ x\ $ being the infimum of $\ S.$

Comment: The lemma that you stated is not of a standard form. But this follows from the standard form, which I’d mentioned in my answer. Pedagogically speaking, it’s better to follow standard forms as far as possible

Comment: What do you mean "of a standard form" ?